# Как отловить событие перехода на другой роутер в vue.js?

Tags: javascript, маршрутизация, vue.js

Есть роутер

```
router.map({
    '/': {
        component: Index
    },
    '/user/:id': {
        component: UserInfo,
        name: 'UserInfo.show'
    },
...
});
```

Мне нужно, что если переходишь по ссылке '/' -сработала функция 1, если по ссыдке- '/user/:id', то функция- 2 . И при обновлении страницы, если роут на ссылке '/user/:id', что б так же сработала функция 2.
Как такое сделать?
(Читал про router.beforeEach(function(transition) ,но это срабатывает, при каждом переходе и не пойму, как разобраться.В ангуляре просто контроллер срабатывал, а здесь нигде не нашёл.)

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас столкнулся с точно такой же задачей, в интернете нет информации об этом. У меня есть меню для мобильных устройств и его нужно закрывать при переходе по `<router-link>`. Отследить переход по ссылке можно:

1. С помощью события `click`. Это не очень удобно, нужно вешать событие на каждую ссылку. Кроме того переход может быть совершён без нажатия на ссылку
2. Следить за `$route.path`

```js
watch: {
    '$route.path'() {
        console.log('Совершён переход по ссылке')
    }
}
```

Comment: замечательный костыль, а в документации все ясно написано про `beforeEach`, который решает этот вопрос.

Comment: @MoloF я знаю, что есть `beforeEach`, но по-моему мнению это понижает читабельность кода и заставляет писать логику для всех view в одном месте, что неудобно, когда разные view должны вести себя по-разному при переходе по ссылкам. Гораздо удобнее, когда логика работы одного view в одном месте, а не разбросана по разным файлам. Моё решение я не считаю костылём. По сути это тоже самое, только в `beforeEach` наша функция выполняется перед переходом, а в моём решении при изменении объекта `$route`. Кроме того моё решение позволяет мне использовать `this`, а ваше - нет

Answer (score 1):

Каждому конкретному можно задать метод **beforeEnter**, но мне кажется, что в представленном кейсе лучше выполнять весь код, который должен срабатывать при переходе в самом компоненте с помощью [этих](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4n%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) хуков.